# CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, PID) возвращает INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

Tags: c++, windows, процесс, ос, модули

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
using namespace std;

DWORD GetPID(const char* ProcessName) {...}

MODULEENTRY32 GetModule(const char* moduleName, unsigned long long ProcessID) {
    MODULEENTRY32 modEntry = { 0 };
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, ProcessID);

    cout << "Started looking for module " << moduleName << " with PID " << ProcessID << "..." << endl;

    if (hSnapshot == NULL || hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        Module32First(hSnapshot, &modEntry);
        cout << "Taking snapshot failed. 4" << endl << "Last error:" << GetLastError() << endl; ;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Modules snapshot had been took successfully!" << endl;
        cout << "Starting modulelist scan..." << endl;

        MODULEENTRY32 curr = { 0 };

        curr.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        if (Module32First(hSnapshot, &curr)) {
            do {
                if (!strcmp(curr.szModule, moduleName)) {
                    cout << "Found " << curr.szModule << " at " << curr.th32ModuleID << " (PID: " << curr.th32ProcessID << ")" << endl;
                    modEntry = curr;
                    break;
                }
                cout << "Found " << curr.szModule << " at " << curr.th32ModuleID << " (PID: " << curr.th32ProcessID << ")" << endl;
            } while (Module32Next(hSnapshot, &curr));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
    }
    return modEntry;
}
int main() {
     unsigned long long pid = GetPID("Process.exe");
     MODULEENTRY32 module = GetModule("process.exe", pid);
}
```

Функция `GetPID` работает нормально, проверил через диспетчер задач; `moduleName` также присвоен правильно.
Так почему же я получаю `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`?

Добавлено: я добавил вывод в консоль тех модулей (в код в вопросе уже внёс изменения), по которым проходится алгоритм, если он всё-таки запускается. И если вызвать GetModule с аргументом ProcessID=0, то вывод будет следующим:

```
Started looking for module Minecraft.Windows.exe with PID 0...
Modules snapshot had been took successfully!
Starting modulelist scan...
Found MCBEBot.exe at 1 (PID: 20732)
Found ntdll.dll at 1 (PID: 20732)
Found KERNEL32.DLL at 1 (PID: 20732)
Found KERNELBASE.dll at 1 (PID: 20732)
Found ucrtbase.dll at 1 (PID: 20732)
Found MSVCP140.dll at 1 (PID: 20732)
Found VCRUNTIME140.dll at 1 (PID: 20732)
Found sechost.dll at 1 (PID: 20732)
Found RPCRT4.dll at 1 (PID: 20732)
```

Т. е. вместо 0 в PID функция `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` подставляет PID того процесса, в котором она запущена. В случае если подставить в PID любое значение (как реальный PID процесса, так и рандомное число). Таким образом, эта функция почему-то может обратиться только к своим модулям. Что делать в таком случае? И почему доступ к процессам происходит нормально, а к модулям - нет?

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: `GetLastError` должна быть вызвана строго до вызова любой другой функции из winapi в этом потоке. Коды ошибок можно посмотреть https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189309/c-return-error-87-on-createtoolhelp32snapshot)

Comment: @user7860670, можете пожалуйста объяснить? Куда мне разместить GetLastError(), если её нельзя вызвать до вызова функции WinAPI, а ошибка происходит именно там? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Сразу после вызова `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, как понимаю...

Comment: Был похожий вопрос, но через другие АПИ, x64-x86 конфликт может быть. Флаги не те могут быть. Прав может нехватать.